# iOS8, Swift: fileURLWithPath - missing argument for parameter error

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl

I am trying to append subdirectory to documents directory using method:

```
class func fileURLWithPath(path: String) -> NSURL?`
```

code:

```
let applicationDocumentsDirectory:String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
let storesDirectory:NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(applicationDocumentsDirectory).URLByAppendingPathComponent("Stores")
```

Getting error

> missing argument for parameter 'isDirectory' in call.

I don't really get it, why compiler requires this parameter? It isn't mentioned in the interface?

Thnanx in advance

Comment: What is `applicationDocumentsDirectory`? If this comes from a Xcode Core Data template app then it is probably an `NSURL`  and not a `String`, so passing it as an argument to `fileURLWithPath()` makes no sense.

Comment: let applicationDocumentsDirectory:String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString

Comment: As usual it helps to provide example data in a question, add that to the question. It also helps debug when there are individual statements in place of a large compound statement, there is no advantage to combining several things into a single statement.

Comment: Don't you see my let storesDirectory?

Comment: Yes and there is more than one potential failure in the one statement.

Comment: As Martin said: What is `applicationDocumentsDirectory`? What is `NFConstants.NFCoreDataStringIdentifiers.CoreDataStoresPathComponent.rawValue` which has possible multiple failures and is possibly a Law of Demeter violation. Not to mention the statement length of 160+ characters.

Comment: edited NFConstants.NFCoreDataStringIdentifiers.CoreDataStoresPathComponent.rawValue = "Stores"

Comment: @NathFur: The error message is misleading. As so often, the reason is that `fileURLWithPath()` returns an *optional*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to chain methods when there are optionals in the chain.

`NSURL.fileURLWithPath(applicationDocumentsDirectory)` returns `NSURL?` type. When you try to execute method `URLByAppendingPathComponent` on it, it throws a compiler error.

I know it's kind of sucks that the compiler error is totally unrelated to the real cause, but it's just a beauty of current Swift version.

Use `!` to unwrap and it's gonna work properly:

```
let storesDirectory:NSURL = 
NSURL.fileURLWithPath(applicationDocumentsDirectory)!
     .URLByAppendingPathComponent(NFConstants.NFCoreDataStringIdentifiers.CoreDataStoresPathComponent.rawValue)
```

Of course force unwrapping the optional is potentially crashy, so even better use `if let` idiom:

```
if let baseUrl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(applicationDocumentsDirectory) {
    let storeURL = baseUrl.URLByAppendingPathComponent(NFConstants.NFCoreDataStringIdentifiers.CoreDataStoresPathComponent.rawValue)
}
```